# How to make a Thread from its ExecutorService communicate with a Runnable?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice

I'm currently using `ExecutorService` for parsing files:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

and later:

```
service.submit(new FileParser(file));
```

However the tools used to parse the files require an initialization which takes quite long. I'd like to perform the initialization only once per thread (not once for all because initialization parameters are not thread-safe), and then to perform only the parsing in the submitted runnable.

I saw that `ThreadFactory` can be used to provide my own threads to the executor, so I could initialize my parameters this way:

```
public class MyThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new MyThread(); // Initialization part inside the constructor
    }
}
```

However then I have no idea on how to provide the new file to parse to the thread...
Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Does the necessary initialization depend on the file to parse? Then it seems, that you have to do it while creating a FileParser. ThreadFactory.newThread will be called by the ExecutorService. In fact, the argument will not be your Runnable (i.e. the FileParser), but it will be a wrapping Worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variable for this initialization. During each execution, you can check if you have executed initialization for current thread and then use it for storing whatever you need.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks!
I initialized everything in the Thread's "run" and used ThreadLocal to keep all new Runnables aware of init parameters, it worked perfectly and my whole process is much faster now!